# How to show model name of mobile when using mobile

Tags: php

```
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if(preg_match('/iPhone/i', $agent)){
    echo "You're using Iphone";
} else if(preg_match('/Android/i', $agent)){
    echo "You're using Iphone";
} else if(preg_match('/Blackberry/i', $agent)){
    echo "You're using Blackberry";
}
```

How to ideas when run a mobile is how model name, ex: Iphone => show model is Iphone 4S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using library called [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/).

This this, you can just easily do:

```
$user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows Phone OS 7.5; Trident/5.0; IEMobile/9.0; NOKIA; Lumia 800)";
$requestingDevice = $wurflManager->getDeviceForUserAgent($user_agent);
$is_wireless = ($requestingDevice->getCapability('is_wireless_device') == 'true');
$is_smarttv = ($requestingDevice->getCapability('is_smarttv') == 'true');
$is_tablet = ($requestingDevice->getCapability('is_tablet') == 'true');
$is_phone = ($requestingDevice->getCapability('can_assign_phone_number') == 'true');
```